# Include some minified and non minifed files in bundles in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

i am building ASP.NET 4.0 MVC web application, in that  i am using some 3rd party jquery plugins / css  where only  minifyed version  available, and i have my own plugins / css.

while using bundle, either minified or non modified version rendered in release and debug mode respectively. i just want to know that , can i include both the minified and non minified files as

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
            "~/assets/plugins/pluginX.min.js",
            "~/assets/plugins/pluginY.js",
            "~/assets/plugins/pluginZ.js",
            "~/assets/js/custom.js",
            "~/assets/js/app.js");
```

as in debug mode the pluginX will not include as the non minifed file not available

or i have to include the files in layout page manually.

i don't want to rename the files. as the files also used in some other places( for example using @import ).

please excuse me if you find the question silly.

Comment: but it will not render on page  in debug mode as the non-minified file not available.

Comment: You can create multiple bundles, use as you like it